# Linux weird problem touch : command not found?

Tags: linux

I occurred a really weired problem, which is touch : command not found.

I was going to create a blank file, so I type the touch command which didn't work.

I'm running centOS 5.

Any ideas?

BTW: the vi command also not found.

And I didn't find touch in the /bin dir, how can I reinstall "touch"?

Comment: Stop crossposting. http://superuser.com/questions/138964/linux-weird-problem-touch-command-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin/touch` is in the coreutils package. You can install this package by running:

```
yum install coreutils
```

If `yum` reports that the package is already installed, then you can run the following commands to reinstall it:

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps coreutils
yum install coreutils
```

The `rpm` command removes the rpm database entry for coreutils, which will allow `yum` to install it again.

`vi` can be installed from either the `vim-minimal` or `vim-enhanced` packages.

Comment: It works, and all the issues has gone!

Really Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

At first guess, i'd say your `$PATH` variable is either empty or broken.  Try typing the commands in their entirety, complete with path:

```
/usr/bin/touch test.txt
/usr/bin/vi test.txt
```

This is assuming CentOS 5 keeps them in `/usr/bin` (which I don't have handy to confirm, you can also try `/bin`)

Also, while you're at it:

```
/usr/bin/echo $PATH
```

and make sure `/usr/bin` (or wherever) is listed in there.

Comment: bash: /usr/bin/touch: No such file or directory
bash: /bin/touch: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/bin/echo: No such file or directory

Comment: this is my $PATH(root)

/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Answer (score 0):

Since it isn't your PATH, it sounds like you can access much of anything.

The first thing I would do is see if your permissions are all messed up for some reason.  This of course assumes you can access either `stat` or `ls`.

I would also check your `/var/log` of `dmesg` to see if you have had a disk error on such a scale that it is not even read-only, or if it is, things have gone really bad.